# Broken labels in eclipse in darkmode

Tags: eclipse, label, darkmode

As soon as I start using **dark mode** in eclipse my labels get weird names:
[image]

when I go back to **light mode** everything is normal

[image]

I am using an older version of eclipse

[image]

Please help, and save my eyes :|

Comment: Can you please [read about when & why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to add transcriptions of your images of text into actual text? See [/editing-help](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks. (no need to transcribe the whole image- just the part about the version numbers is fine)

Comment: "I am using an older version of eclipse" Well, what happens in the *current* version?

Comment: It's the used font. Please make sure your software is up to date before asking.

Comment: Why are you using an older Eclipse? That release is 3 years and 9 releases old. Note that most Eclipse downloads include a suitable Java JRE internally for running Eclipse itself so you don't have to change your main Java install.